# How to display embedded Closed Captions for HLS stream in Windows 10 UWP app?

Tags: uwp, mediaelement, http-live-streaming, closed-captions

I'm trying to play **HLS stream in Windows 10 UWP app**. [This stream](http://nasatv-lh.akamaihd.net/i/NASA_101@319270/master.m3u8) contains **embedded captions** that can be turned on in VLC player or in Edge browser when playing the HLS stream directly.

Is there a way how to **show these embedded captions in UWP MediaElement** as well?

I've tried using this approach but no textSources are loaded or shown when using these steps:

```
Uri source = new Uri("http://nasatv-lh.akamaihd.net/i/NASA_101@319270/master.m3u8");
AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationResult result = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(source);

if (result.Status == AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationStatus.Success)
{
    AdaptiveMediaSource astream = result.MediaSource;
    MediaSource mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromAdaptiveMediaSource(astream);
    var metadataTracks = mediaSource.ExternalTimedMetadataTracks.ToArray();
    var textSources = mediaSource.ExternalTimedTextSources.ToArray();
    // both arrays above are empty when loading the NASA TV stream

    MediaPlaybackItem mediaElement = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);
    Player.SetPlaybackSource(mediaElement);
}
```

Note I've tried to use the Player Framework as well, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to show these embedded captions in UWP MediaElement?

To show the embedded captions in [this stream](http://nasatv-lh.akamaihd.net/i/NASA_101@319270/master.m3u8), you can just set the URI as  `MediaElement`'s [`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.source.aspx) and change [`AreTransportControlsEnabled` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aretransportcontrolsenabled.aspx) to `true` to enable the standard transport controls.

```xaml
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement"
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
              Source="http://nasatv-lh.akamaihd.net/i/NASA_101@319270/master.m3u8" />
```

Once it has valid captions, the closed caption menu will show and we can use it to control whether to display closed captions like following:
[image]

[MediaSource.ExternalTimedMetadataTracks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn930915) and [MediaSource.ExternalTimedTextSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn930916) property are used for get **external**  timed metadata tracks or text sources associated with the MediaSource. As the captions in the stream are embedded and you didn't add [TimedTextSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.core.timedtextsource) in `ExternalTimedTextSources` so there is no `textSources`.

Comment: Thanks, I never found info about this switch including the fact it automatically processes the subtitles as well!